# Is a level set of a continuous function a closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis

$f: \mathbb R^{n}\to \mathbb R^{n}$ ($n\geq 2$) is a continuous function.

Let
$$M=\{x\in \mathbb R^n~|~f(x)=0\}$$

Is $M$ a closed set? If not, can you give a counter example.

Comment: Yes, assuming that singleton points are closed in the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  (They are in the standard metric topology.)

Comment: how about: $f^i:R^n\to R^n$ is a continuous function for $i=1,2$.Let
$$M=\{(x,y)\in R^{2n} | f^1(x)+f^2(y)=0\}$$
Is M a closed set?

Comment: You ought to ask this as a separate question.  The short answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $M=f^{-1}({\{0\}})$ so $M$ is closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ by the continuous function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For all $y\neq 0$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $0\notin V$. Then the preimage of this $V$ is necessarily an open set (by continuity), and it follows that $M^c$ is open, and therefore that $M$ is closed.