# A Fourier Analysis Question I am stuck at

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> If $f,g\in C[-\pi,\pi]$,and $f,g$ are $2\pi$ periodic, prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)g(nt)\mathbb dt=\big(\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\mathbb dt\big)\big(\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t)\mathbb dt\big)$$

I tried to approximate $g(nt)$ by a trigonometric polynomial $T_n(t)$ but the problem is that $n$ is varying here. Nothing seems to work. I tried to interpret the left side as the constant Fourier coefficient of the function $f(x)g(nx)$ and the right side as the product of constant Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ but because $f$ and $g$ are just continuous and not Lipschitz, I cannot replace $f$ and $g$ by their Fourier sums.

Please give me a hint only to get started on this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A generalized version of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90195/a-generalized-version-of-the-riemann-lebesgue-lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$ be
$$
      a_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx,\;\;\;
      b_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ikx}g(x)dx.
$$
Then $g(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{k}e^{ikx}$ converges in $L^{2}$ on any finite interval to the periodic extension of $g$. More explicitly, if $S_{N}=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}b_{k}e^{ikx}$, then, for fixed $n=1,2,3,\cdots$,
$$
         \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{2n\pi}|g(x)-S_{N}(x)|^{2}dx= 0.
$$
By a simple change of variables, for fixed $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, one has
$$
         \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|g(nx)-S_{N}(nx)|^{2}dx = 0.
$$
Then, for $f \in L^{2}$, it follows that, for fixed $n=1,2,3,\cdots$,
$$
         \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(nx)dx = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)S_{N}(nx)dx.
$$
The above is easily justified using Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
     \left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(nx)dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)S_{N}(nx)dx\right| \\
      \le \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)||g(nx)-S_{N}(nx)|dx \\
      \le \left[\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)|^{2}\right]^{1/2}
          \left[\int_{0}^{2\pi}|g(nx)-S_{N}(nx)|^{2}\right]^{1/2}\rightarrow 0
    \mbox{ as } N \rightarrow \infty \mbox{ for fixed n. }
$$

Therefore, for any fixed $n=1,2,3,\cdots,$
$$
\begin{align}
      \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(nx)dx &
            =\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)S_{N}(nx)dx \\
       & = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\sum_{k=-N}^{N}b_{k}e^{iknx} dx \\
       & = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=-N}^{N}b_{k}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{iknx}dx \\
       & = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=-N}^{N}b_{k}a_{-kn} \\
       & = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{k}a_{-kn}.
\end{align}
$$
Finally, Applying Cauchy-Schwarz to the sum on the right gives
$$
\begin{align}
  \left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)g(nx)dx-a_{0}b_{0}\right|^{2}
   & = \left|\sum_{|k| \ge 1}b_{k}a_{kn}\right|^{2} \\
   & \le \sum_{|k|\ge 1}|b_{k}|^{2}\sum_{|k|\ge 1}|a_{kn}|^{2} \\
   & \le \sum_{|k|\ge 1}|b_{k}|^{2}\sum_{|k| \ge n}|a_{k}|^{2}\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
$$
The last term on the right tends to $0$ because the sum is convergent.

Comment: Whoever downvoted could ask a question if they don't understand.

Comment: Hello T.A.E.! I did not downvote your answer but I would like you to explain some things like:
1. Why does the fact that the Fourier series of $g$ converges in $L^2$ to $g$ imply I can replace $g$ by its Fourier sum? I don't think we can do that, because $g$ will need to be at least Lipschitz in this case, not only continuous. 
2. How did you interchange the summation and integral? Thing is, we do not know about uniform convergence of the Fourier series to the function.
3. Would you mind explaining the last inequality? Thanks!!

Comment: @yedaynara : The Fourier series for $f \in L^{2}$ always converges in the norm of $L^{2}$ to $f$. If $S_{N}$ is the truncated Fourier series $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inx}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(y)e^{-iny}dy$, then $\|S_{N}-f\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, if $g$ is also in $L^{2}$, then $\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)S_{N}(x)dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)f(x)dx\right| \le \|g\|_{L^{2}}\|f-S_{N}\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: This is not a very straightforward problem, at least according to me. Could you kindly edit your answer and write the steps more clearly, explaining how you got each step? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know the classical $L^2$ results of Fourier Series? For example, $e_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{inx}$ defines a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}$. So $\|f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(f,e_{n})e_{n}\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$. Parseval's identity is equivalent: $\|f\|^{2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|(f,e_n)|^{2}$. Equivalently, $(f,g)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e_{n})(e_{n},g)$. Then there is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|\sum_{n}a_{n}b_{n}|^{2}\le \sum_{n}|a_{n}|^2\sum_{n}|b_{n}|^2$. If you know these, then my solution will make sense, and I can expand more. If not ...

Comment: @yedaynara : I forgot to ping you in the last message.

Comment: I know all these. But, still I do not get your solution at the parts I mentioned. Please expand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22519/discussion-between-yedaynara-and-t-a-e).

Comment: @yedaynara : Please look at the edited, expanded version now posted using the results that I cited, and that you stated you knew to be true. Ask more questions if something is not clear. I don't have time to chat today.

Comment: Perfect now, thanks a lot. Accepting this as the final answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the real form of Fourier series.
The first thing that we examine is the integral $\frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt} $.

If we can determine this integral, then we can work out the limit.
Both *f* and *g* are continuous and therefore square integrable.  Note  that since they are both periodic of period 2$\pi$, the convergence properties of the Fourier series of both functions should be useful.  Though their Fourier series converge almost everywhere in $[-\pi, \pi]$, but this property is of little use.  But since they are both square integrable, their Fourier series converge respectively to  $f$ and  $g$  in the *L<sup>2</sup>* norm.

Let the Fourier series of  $f$  be

$T(\theta ) = \frac{1}{2}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{a_j}\cos (j\theta ) + {b_j}\sin (j\theta )} \right)} $
and  the Fourier series of $g$ be

$S(\theta ) = \frac{1}{2}{A_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_j}\cos (j\theta ) + {B_j}\sin (j\theta )} \right)} $

and

${T_k}(\theta ) = \frac{1}{2}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k {\left( {{a_j}\cos (j\theta ) + {b_j}\sin (j\theta )} \right)} $ and

${S_k}(\theta ) = \frac{1}{2}{A_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {\left( {{A_j}\cos (j\theta ) + {B_j}\sin (j\theta )} \right)} $
their respective partial sums.

Then convergence in the *L<sup>2</sup>* norm means 
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left| {{T_k}(t) - f(t)} \right|}^2}}  = 0$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left| {{S_k}(t) - g(t)} \right|}^2}}  = 0$.

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer.

Then we also have that
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int_{ - n\pi }^{n\pi } {{{\left| {{S_k}(t) - g(t)} \right|}^2}}  = 0$.

Thus by a change of variable we get
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } n\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left| {{S_k}(nt) - g(nt)} \right|}^2}dt}  = 0$ and so 

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left| {{S_k}(nt) - g(nt)} \right|}^2}dt}  = 0$.

This means ${S_k}(nt)$ tends to $g(nt)$ in the *L<sup>2</sup>* norm and we have $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt} $ tends to $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt}$.

We can deduce this statement as follows:
$\left| {\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt}  - \frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt} } \right|$

$ \le \frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {|f(t)||{S_k}(nt) - g(nt)|dt} $

$ \le \frac{1}{\pi }\sqrt {\left( {\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {|f(t){|^2}dt} } \right)} \sqrt {\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {|{S_k}(nt) - g(nt){|^2}dt} }$  by Holder’s Inequality.

Since $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left| {{S_k}(nt) - g(nt)} \right|}^2}dt}  = 0$, the right hand side of the above inequality tends to 0 and so by the Comparison Test,

$\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt} $ tends to $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt} $ as $k$ tends to infinity.

We now compute $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt} $.

Since $f(t){S_k}(nt) = \frac{1}{2}{A_0}f(t) + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {\left( {{A_j}f(t)\cos (jnt) + {B_j}f(t)\sin (jnt)} \right)} $ ,

$\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt}  = \frac{1}{2}{A_0}\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)dt}  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {\left( {{A_j}\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)\cos (jnt)} dt + {B_j}\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)\sin (jnt)dt} } \right)} $

$ = \frac{1}{2}{A_0}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)} $.

It follows that 
$\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t){S_k}(nt)dt}  \to \frac{1}{2}{A_0}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)} $
as $k$ tends to infinity.

Hence $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt}  = \frac{1}{2}{A_0}{a_0} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = \infty } {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)} $.

Now we claim that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)}  = 0$.

Observe that $\left| {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)} } \right| \le \left| {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {{A_j}{a_{jn}}} } \right| + \left| {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {{B_j}{b_{jn}}} } \right| \le \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {{A_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {a_{jn}^2} }  + \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {{B_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{j = k} {b_{jn}^2} } $

by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality,

$ \le \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{A_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {a_{jn}^2} }  + \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{B_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {b_{jn}^2} } $.

And so $\left| {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)} } \right| \le \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{A_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {a_{jn}^2} }  + \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{B_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {b_{jn}^2} } $

$ \le \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{A_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = n}^\infty  {a_j^2} }  + \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{B_j}^2} } \sqrt {\sum\limits_{j = n}^\infty  {b_j^2} } $ .

Note that $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {|g(t){|^2}dt}  = \frac{1}{2}A_0^2 + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {A_j^2 + B_j^2} \right)} $  and  $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {|f(t){|^2}dt}  = \frac{1}{2}a_0^2 + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {a_j^2 + b_j^2} \right)} $.

So both $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {a_j^2} $ and  $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {b_j^2} $ are finite and as a consequence,

$\sum\limits_{j = n}^\infty  {a_j^2}  \to 0{\rm{ }}\quad {\rm{and }}\quad \sum\limits_{j = n}^\infty  {b_j^2}  \to 0{\rm{ }}\quad {\rm{as }}\;n \to \infty $ .

And so it follows from the above inequality that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_j}{a_{jn}} + {B_j}{b_{jn}}} \right)}  = 0$.

Hence $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt}  = \frac{1}{2}{A_0}{a_0} = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)dt} \frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {g(t)dt} $,

i.e., $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)g(nt)dt}  = \left( {\frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)dt} } \right)\left( {\frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {g(t)dt} } \right)$.

Observe that I only use the fact that both functions are periodic, Lebesgue integrable and square integrable. The continuity of both $f$ and $g$ is used only to deduce both integrablity and square integrability. *We may of course replace the condition on continuity by Lebsgue integrability and square integrability.*

Answer (score -2):

Hint: write $g(t)$ as the combination of $\sin(kt)$ and $\cos(kt)$, i.e., you need only solve the problem for $g(t)=\sin(kt)$ or $\cos(kt)$ for some $k$.

Comment: How can I? They are just continuous. Not differentiable or Lipschitz of something like that. How do I know that the Fourier series converges? Could you kindly elaborate your hint? Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, and then using that $f$ is Riemann integrable to split $f$ up over a partition of $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Alternative suggestion: Fejér sums?

---

Okay, I've thought about this some more, and I think it comes down to one of the following lemmata:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $g$ be as in the question, and let $\chi_A$ be the indicator function of a closed subset in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \chi_A(t)g(nt) \, dt = \mu(A) \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(t) \, dt \right) $$

(From here, I use the usual increasing sequence of step functions argument for Lebesgue integration) (Why do closed sets suffice? For a continuous function, the level sets are closed - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337651/is-a-level-set-of-a-continuous-function-a-closed-set).)

or

> **Lemma 2:** Let $g$ be as in the question, and let $\chi_A$ be the indicator function of an interval in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \chi_A(t)g(nt) \, dt = \mu(A) \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(t) \, dt \right) $$

(This is obviously sufficient to prove the other one, using the Heine-Borel theorem.)

Then you use that and the properties of Riemann sums to sandwich $f$ and take the limit to get the integral. Lemma 2 looks pretty easy to prove.

Comment: If a function is uniformly continuous, it may not be Lipschitz, so maybe we cannot replace it by its Fourier series. Are you suggesting writing $f=(f-T(t))+T(t)$ where $T$ is a trigonometric polynomial? As for the alternative suggestion, I did try to replace $g(nt)$ by Fejer sum but problem is, $n$ is varying, so at different points I am getting different Fejer sums.

Comment: I suppose what I actually mean is to approximate $f$ by some Riemann sums. $g$ is probably best left to its own devices.

Comment: Okay. Well I had never thought of doing anything on $f$. So maybe you are suggesting the use of the fact that there exists a step function approximating $f$.

Comment: Yes, that I expect would work. The interesting question is whether a Riemann-type step function or a Lebesgue-type one is easier to work with.

Comment: Umm, I really couldn't find a way to proceed after using a step function. The terms are not going to $0$ because $\int g(nt)s(t)dt$ may not go to $0$. If we were dealing with Trigonometric polynomials then we could have used Riemann Lebesgue Lemma, which would have guaranteed convergence to $0$. But working with a trigonometric polynomial approximating $g$ when $n$ is varying is hard enough.

Comment: @yedaynara I've edited my answer to be more specific. I think that's probably the right technique.

Comment: I should like to know what about my answer makes it deserve downvotes: this process does answer the question in the form posed.